# Difference between == and ===

Tags: swift

In swift there seem to be two equality operators: the double equals (**`==`**) and the triple equals (**`===`**), what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

**In short:**

**`==`** operator checks if their instance values are equal, **`"equal to"`**

**`===`** operator checks if the references point the same instance, **`"identical to"`**

**Long Answer:**

Classes are reference types, it is possible for multiple constants and variables to refer to the same single instance of a class behind the scenes. Class references stay in Run Time Stack (RTS) and their instances stay in Heap area of Memory. When you control equality with **`==`** it means if their instances are equal to each other. It doesn't need to be same instance to be equal. For this you need to provide a equality criteria to your custom class. By default, custom classes and structures do not receive a default implementation of the equivalence operators, known as the “equal to” operator **`==`** and “not equal to” operator **`!=`** . To do this your custom class needs to conform **`Equatable`** protocol and it's **`static func == (lhs:, rhs:) -> Bool`** function

Let's look at example:

```
class Person : Equatable {
    let ssn: Int
    let name: String

    init(ssn: Int, name: String) {
        self.ssn = ssn
        self.name = name
    }

    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.ssn == rhs.ssn
    }
}
```

**`P.S.:`** Since ssn(social security number) is a unique number, you don't need to compare if their name are equal or not.

```
let person1 = Person(ssn: 5, name: "Bob")
let person2 = Person(ssn: 5, name: "Bob")

if person1 == person2 {
   print("the two instances are equal!")
}
```

Although person1 and person2 references point two different instances in Heap area, their instances are equal because their ssn numbers are equal. So the output will be `the two instance are equal!`

```
if person1 === person2 {
   //It does not enter here
} else {
   print("the two instances are not identical!")
}
```

**`===`** operator checks if the references point the same instance, **`"identical to"`**. Since person1 and person2 have two different instance in Heap area, they are not identical and the output `the two instance are not identical!`

```
let person3 = person1
```

**`P.S:`** Classes are reference types and person1's reference is copied to person3 with this assignment operation, thus both references point the same instance in Heap area.

```
if person3 === person1 {
   print("the two instances are identical!")
}
```

They are identical and the output will be `the two instances are identical!`

Answer (score 263):

`!==` and `===` are identity operators and are used to determine if two objects have the same reference.

> Swift also provides two identity operators (=== and !==), which you use to test whether two object references both refer to the same object instance.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: Yup. Coming from ObjC, `==` is `isEqual:`, or class-defined semantic equivalence. `===` in Swift is `==` in (Obj)C — pointer equality, or object identity.

Comment: @rickster Dont' values also have a memory location? I'm eventually they are somewhere in the memory. Can't you ever compare those? Or is that their memory location doesn't offer any *meaningful* value?

Comment: There's at least two ways to think about how the language defines value types vs memory. One is that each binding (`var` or `let`) of a name to a value is a unique copy — so it's meaningless to create pointers because the value you made a pointer to is a different value than the one you first created. Another is that Swift's definition of value semantics abstracts away the storage — the compiler is free to optimize, up to and including never storing your value at a memory location accessible beyond the line where it's used (register, instruction encoding, etc).

Answer (score 63):

In both Objective-C and Swift, the `==` and `!=` operators test for value equality for number values (e.g., `NSInteger`, `NSUInteger`, `int`, in Objective-C and `Int`, `UInt`, etc. in Swift). For objects (NSObject/NSNumber and subclasses in Objective-C and reference types in Swift), `==` and `!=` test that the objects/reference types are the same identical thing -- i.e., same hash value -- or are not the same identical thing, respectively.

```
let a = NSObject()
let b = NSObject()
let c = a
a == b // false
a == c // true
```

Swift's *identity equality* operators, `===` and `!==`, check referential equality -- and thus, should probably be called the *referential equality* operators IMO.

```
a === b // false
a === c // true
```

It's also worth pointing out that custom reference types in Swift (that do not subclass a class that conforms to Equatable) do not automatically implement the equal to operators, but the *identity equality* operators still apply. Also, by implementing `==`, `!=` is automatically implemented.

```
class MyClass: Equatable {
  let myProperty: String

  init(s: String) {
    myProperty = s
  }
}

func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
  return lhs.myProperty == rhs.myProperty
}

let myClass1 = MyClass(s: "Hello")
let myClass2 = MyClass(s: "Hello")
myClass1 == myClass2 // true
myClass1 != myClass2 // false
myClass1 === myClass2 // false
myClass1 !== myClass2 // true
```

These equality operators are not implemented for other types such as structures in either language. However, custom operators can be created in Swift, which would, for example, enable you to create an operator to check equality of a CGPoint.

```
infix operator <==> { precedence 130 }
func <==> (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> Bool {
  return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
}

let point1 = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
let point2 = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
point1 <==> point2 // true
```

Comment: Sorry, but in Obj-C the == operator does NOT compare for EQUALITY, but rather - like C - compares pointer references (object Identity).

Comment: `==` does not test for `NSNumber` equality in Objective-C. `NSNumber` is an `NSObject` so it tests for identity. The reason it SOMETIMES works is because of tagged pointers/cached object literals. It will fail for large enough numbers and on 32-bit devices when comparing non-literals.

Answer (score 51):

## In swift 3 and above

#### `===` (or `!==`)

- Checks if the values are **identical** *(both point to the same memory address)*.
- Comparing **reference types**.
- Like `==` in Obj-C (pointer equality).

#### `==` (or `!=`)

- Checks if the values are **the same**.
- Comparing **value types**.
- Like the default `isEqual:` in Obj-C behavior.

**Here I compare three instances** *(class is a reference type)*

```
class Person {}

let person = Person()
let person2 = person
let person3 = Person()

person === person2 // true
person === person3 // false
```

Comment: You can also override `isEqual:` in Swift: `override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {}`

Answer (score 37):

There are subtleties with Swifts `===` that go beyond mere pointer arithmetics. While in Objective-C you were able to compare any two pointers (i.e. `NSObject *`) with `==` this is no longer true in Swift since types play a much greater role during compilation.

A Playground will give you

```
1 === 2                    // false
1 === 1                    // true
let one = 1                // 1
1 === one                  // compile error: Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
1 === (one as AnyObject)   // true (surprisingly (to me at least))
```

With strings we will have to get used to this:

```
var st = "123"                                 // "123"
var ns = (st as NSString)                      // "123"
st == ns                                       // true, content equality
st === ns                                      // compile error
ns === (st as NSString)                        // false, new struct
ns === (st as AnyObject)                       // false, new struct
(st as NSString) === (st as NSString)          // false, new structs, bridging is not "free" (as in "lunch")
NSString(string:st) === NSString(string:st)    // false, new structs
var st1 = NSString(string:st)                  // "123"
var st2 = st1                                  // "123"
st1 === st2                                    // true
var st3 = (st as NSString)                     // "123"
st1 === st3                                    // false
(st as AnyObject) === (st as AnyObject)        // false
```

but then you can also have fun as follows:

```
var st4 = st             // "123"
st4 == st                // true
st4 += "5"               // "1235"
st4 == st                // false, not quite a reference, copy on write semantics
```

I am sure you can think of a lot more funny cases :-)

**Update for Swift 3** (as suggested by the comment from Jakub Truhlář)

```
1===2                                    // Compiler error: binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands
(1 as AnyObject) === (2 as AnyObject)    // false
let two = 2
(2 as AnyObject) === (two as AnyObject)  // false (rather unpleasant)
(2 as AnyObject) === (2 as AnyObject)    // false (this makes it clear that there are new objects being generated)
```

This looks a little more consistent with `Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`, however we then get

```
type(of:(1 as AnyObject))                // _SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber.Type
```

but the explicit conversion makes clear that there might be something going on.
On the String-side of things `NSString` will still be available as long as we `import Cocoa`. Then we will have

```
var st = "123"                                 // "123"
var ns = (st as NSString)                      // "123"
st == ns                                       // Compile error with Fixit: 'NSString' is not implicitly convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?
st == ns as String                             // true, content equality
st === ns                                      // compile error: binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'NSString'
ns === (st as NSString)                        // false, new struct
ns === (st as AnyObject)                       // false, new struct
(st as NSString) === (st as NSString)          // false, new structs, bridging is not "free" (as in "lunch")
NSString(string:st) === NSString(string:st)    // false, new objects
var st1 = NSString(string:st)                  // "123"
var st2 = st1                                  // "123"
st1 === st2                                    // true
var st3 = (st as NSString)                     // "123"
st1 === st3                                    // false
(st as AnyObject) === (st as AnyObject)        // false
```

It is still confusing to have two String classes, but dropping the implicit conversion will probably make it a *little* more palpable.

Comment: You can't use `===` operator to compare `Ints`. Not in Swift 3.

Comment: Whenever you say a "new struct" is being created, what's actually happening is a new object (of a *class* type) is being created. `===` is meaningless for structs since they're value types. In particular, there's three types you need to keep in mind: literal types, such as 1 or "foo", which haven't been bound to a variable and normally only affect compilation since you generally don't deal with them during runtime; struct types such as `Int` and `String` which are what you get when you assign a literal to a variable, and classes such as `AnyObject` and `NSString`.

Answer (score 13):

For example, if you create two instances of a class e.g. `myClass`:

```
var inst1 = myClass()
var inst2 = myClass()
```

you can compare those instances,

```
if inst1 === inst2
```

cited:

> which you use to test whether two object references both refer to the
>   same object instance.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/sk/jEUH0.l

Comment: Actually this is just to show how we can compare. Result of the above statement is false since separate memory gets allocated in for each instance inst1 and inst2.
if inst1 === inst2 {
    print("Here we get false")
}
var inst3 = inst1
 if inst1 === inst3 {
      print("Here we get true")
}

Comment: @vin of course. As the excerpt said _test whether two object references both refer to the **same** object instance_. The `var inst1 = myClass()
var inst2 = myClass()` **are** two different instances.

Comment: Earlier I was relating it with isKindOfClass. I realized that it's not!

Answer (score 11):

In Swift we have **===** simbol which means is both objects are referring to the same reference same address

```
class SomeClass {

    var a: Int

    init(_ a: Int) {
        self.a = a
    }
}

var someClass1 = SomeClass(4)
var someClass2 = SomeClass(4)
someClass1 === someClass2 // false
someClass2 = someClass1
someClass1 === someClass2 // true
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a minor contribution related to the `Any` object.

I was working with unit tests around `NotificationCenter`, which makes use of `Any` as a parameter that I wanted to compare for equality.

However, since `Any` cannot be used in an equality operation, it was necessary to change it. Ultimately, I settled on the following approach, which allowed me to get equality in my specific situation, shown here with a simplistic example:

```
func compareTwoAny(a: Any, b: Any) -> Bool {
    return ObjectIdentifier(a as AnyObject) == ObjectIdentifier(b as AnyObject)
}
```

This function takes advantage of [ObjectIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/objectidentifier), which provides a unique address for the object, allowing me to test.

One item to note though about `ObjectIdentifier` per Apple at the above link:

> In Swift, only class instances and metatypes have unique identities.
>   There is no notion of identity for structs, enums, functions, or
>   tuples.

Answer (score 2):

`==` is used to check if two variables are equal i.e 
`2 == 2`. But in case of `===` it stands for equality i.e if two instances referring  to the same object example in case of classes a reference is created which is held by many other instances.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4: Another example using *Unit Tests* which only works with ===**

*Note: Test below fails with ==, works with ===*

```
func test_inputTextFields_Delegate_is_ViewControllerUnderTest() {

        //instantiate viewControllerUnderTest from Main storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        viewControllerUnderTest = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoryBoardIdentifier") as! ViewControllerUnderTest 
        let _ = viewControllerUnderTest.view

        XCTAssertTrue(viewControllerUnderTest.inputTextField.delegate === viewControllerUnderTest) 
    }
```

And the class being

```
class ViewControllerUnderTest: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        inputTextField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

The error in Unit Tests if you use == is, `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UITextFieldDelegate?' and 'ViewControllerUnderTest!'`