# Most elegant way to compare two optionals in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I have two `AnyObject?` variables that I would like to compare for reference equality:

```
var oldValue: AnyObject?
var newValue: AnyObject?
...
if oldValue != newValue {
    changed = true
}
```

This doesn't work though, as I apparently cannot compare two optionals directly. I want the behavior as if I were comparing `id`s in Objective-C, that is:

- `true` if both are `nil`
- `true` if both have a value and the values are also equal
- `false` otherwise

Is there an elegant way to write this in Swift (ideally without having to write a custom extension)?

This is the best I've come up with:

```
if !(oldValue != nil && newValue != nil && oldValue == newValue)
```

Not very pretty. :(

Comment: You could use `!==` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002819/difference-between-and for reference.

Comment: Is that really it?! I keep forgetting about that operator!

Comment: @sbarow I think you got it actually. Post the answer if you want the rep.

Comment: Reference comparison is what I want. I didn't post the code where the variables get their values.

Comment: I can't forget that operator due to Javascript and its funky behaviour with `==` and `===` ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `!==`

From **The Swift Programming Language**

> Swift also provides two identity operators (`===` and `!==`), which you use to test wether two objects references both refer to the same object instance.

Some good examples and explanations are also at [Difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002819/difference-between-and)

On @PEEJWEEJ point, doing the following will result in `false`

```
var newValue: AnyObject? = "String"
var oldValue: AnyObject? = "String"

if newValue === oldValue {
   print("true")
} else {
   print("false")
}
```

Comment: FYI, I think if oldValue and newValue are objects, === will always be false unless they're actually set to the same object.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you're using Comparable entities, this will work on anything:

```
func optionalsAreEqual<T: Comparable>(firstVal: T?, secondVal: T?) -> Bool{

    if let firstVal = firstVal, secondVal = secondVal {
        return firstVal == secondVal
    }
    else{
        return firstVal == nil && secondVal == nil
   }
}
```

It's not exactly short and sweet, but it's expressive, clear, and reusable.

Comment: Though it's not exactly what I was looking for, thanks for posting this in case others are looking for a non-reference comparison.

Answer (score 9):

I liked [@Keith's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021947/6829420) solution. But I think it is not written in Swift 4, as I can not compile it with Swift 4 compiler.

So I have converted his code to Swift 4 version here.

Remember, if you're using higher version of Swift language than **Swift 4.1**, then **this answer is of no need** as it provides this feature by default. You can refer [here](https://swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/) for more details.

**Swift 4 version of @Keith's code:**

```
infix operator ==? : ComparisonPrecedence

func ==? <T: Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    if let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs {
        return lhs == rhs
    } else {
        return lhs == nil && rhs == nil
    }
}

func ==? <T: AnyObject>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    if let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs {
        return lhs === rhs
    } else {
        return lhs == nil && rhs == nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the note that this no longer applies after 4.1.

Answer (score 3):

I define a custom infix operator with a function for both reference types and value types.

```
func ==? <T: Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    if let lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs {
        return lhs == rhs
    } else{ return lhs == nil && rhs == nil }
}
func ==? <T: AnyObject>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    if let lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs {
        return lhs === rhs
    } else{ return lhs == nil && rhs == nil }
}
infix operator ==? { associativity left precedence 130 }

var aString: String? = nil
var bString: String? = nil
print(aString ==? bString) // true

aString = "test"
bString = "test"
print(aString ==? bString) // true

aString = "test2"
bString = "test"
print(aString ==? bString) // false

aString = "test"
bString = nil
print(aString ==? bString) // false

class TT {}
let x = TT()

var aClass: TT? = TT()
var bClass: TT? = TT()
print(aClass ==? bClass) // false

aClass = TT()
bClass = nil
print(aClass ==? bClass) // false

aClass = nil
bClass = nil
print(aClass ==? bClass) // true

aClass = x
bClass = x
print(aClass ==? bClass) // true
```

Comment: Isn't Equatable more than enough?

Comment: I assume this is written in Swift 3. I am correct @Keith?

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `==` operator for some `Comparable` type

```
public func ==<T: SomeType>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs,rhs) {
    case (.some(let lhs), .some(let rhs)):
        return lhs == rhs
    case (.none, .none):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Or use `===` comparison for `AnyObject`, though, personally I would prefer not to use `AnyObject` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a Swift 5 version of Keith's older solution **however** this is on generics. If, for example, the thing you are comparing is `String?` it will consider that `String? = nil` is NOT the same as `String? = ""` although both are "empty" at a semantic level

```
func ==? <T: Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    if let lhs = lhs,
       let rhs = rhs {
        return lhs == rhs
    } else { return lhs == nil && rhs == nil }
}
func ==? <T: AnyObject>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    if let lhs = lhs,
       let rhs = rhs {
        return lhs === rhs
    } else { return lhs == nil && rhs == nil }
}
infix operator ==?: ComparisonPrecedence
```