# iOS: How to get the current visible keyboard type?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

How do I find out if the keyboard is of type numeric, Twitter, email, etc...?

edit: Is there a way to detect keyboard type without using an outlet?

Comment: Use `.keyboardType` property of `UITextField` to determine the type.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that you have tow textFields in the ViewController, You will need to implement [textFieldShouldBeginEditing](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619601-textfieldshouldbeginediting?language=objc) method from [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) protocol, as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tfEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfPassword: UITextField!

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.keyboardType == .emailAddress {
            // this is the tfEmail!
        }

        if textField.isSecureTextEntry {
            // this is tfPassword!
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure their *delegates* are connected to the ViewController, programmatically:

```
tfEmail.delegate = self
tfPassword.delegate = self
```

or from the Interface Builder.

Note that you can recognize the keyboard type for the current textField by checking its [keyboardType](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624457-keyboardtype) property, which is an instance of [UIKeyboardType](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uikeyboardtype) enum:

> The type of keyboard to display for a given text-based view. Used with
>   the keyboardType property.

**What about `UITextView`?**

The same exact functionality should be applied when working with UITextViews, but you need to implement [textViewDidBeginEditing(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618610-textviewdidbeginediting) method from [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate) protocol instead of implementing  `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`. Again, make sure the *delegate* of the textView is connected to the ViewController.

**Also,**

If your main purpose of checking the keyboard type is  just for recognizing what is the current responded textField/textView, I suggest to do a direct check:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tfEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewDescription: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tfEmail.delegate = self
        tfPassword.delegate = self

        textViewDescription.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField === tfEmail {
            // this is the tfEmail!
        }

        if textField === tfPassword {
            // this is tfPassword!
        }
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView === textViewDescription {
            // this is description textview
        }
    }
}
```

*For more information about [`===`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1538988) operator you might want to check [this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002819/difference-between-and).*

Hope this helped.

Comment: @Xcoder123 thank you for your note :) I assume that it -somehow- should leads to the same purpose, the OP might need to add some logic for achieving a specific functionality.

Comment: yes, I have added that logic inside my answer :-), and I really wanted to add that logic for the case where no keyboard is visible... And I think having a separate function adds simplicity, because it is easier to access and is a bit more customizable

Comment: Is there a way to detect keyboard type without using an outlet?

Comment: Of course! instead of letting the textField as an IBOultet, you can create one programmatically and setting its delegate to `self`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ***Ahmad F*** 's great answer, this is my approach of getting the current keyboard type, at any time:

---

**Step 1:** Delegate `UITextField`

```
class File: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{//...}
```

Update `viewDidLoad()` to this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var normalTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var numberTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    numberTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    normalTextField.keyboardType = .default
    emailTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
    numberTextField.delegate = self
    normalTextField.delegate = self
    emailTextField.delegate = self
}
```

---

**Step 2:** Working with `UITextField`'s methods:

Add a variable called keyboardType, as below:

```
var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType? = nil
```

Then, change it whenever a new `textField` begins editing:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        keyboardType = textField.keyboardType
}
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        keyboardType = nil
        return true
}
```

---

**Step 3:** Create and call a function like below:

```
func getCurrentKeyboard() -> String{
    if keyboardType == nil{
        return "no current keyboard"
    }
    else if keyboardType == .numberPad{
        return "number"
    }
    else if keyboardType == .emailAddress{
        return "email"
    }
    else{
        return "default"
    }
}

@IBAction func displayCurrentKeyboard(_ sender: UIButton) {
       print(self.getCurrentKeyboard())
}
```

And this outputs: `email / number / no current keyboard / default`, depending on the case.

If you want to check which type of keyboard it is with `if-else` statements, you can change your `displayCurrentKeyboard()` method to this:

```
@IBAction func displayCurrentKeyboard(_ sender: UIButton) {
      let keyboardString = self.getCurrentKeyboard()
      if keyboardString == "number"{
      //...
      }
      else if keyboardString == "email"{
      //...
      }
      else{
      //...
      }
}
```

And that's it! You can call this wherever you want in your code with this usage:

```
 let keyboardString = self.getCurrentKeyboard()
```

**NOTE:** This method also handles the case of no keyboard visible on the screen, returning *`no current keyboard`*, in this case.

Let me know if this helps!