# Swift Unit Testing: Checking for equality of two objects of the same class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, testing

How would you create a test function to compare the contents of two objects of the same class?

Background:
I have a function which extracts data from a CSV file and uses that data to create an object. I want to know if this function is generating the correct output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Equatable protocol. E.g.

```
extension MyClass: Equatable
{
  static func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool
  {
    return (lhs.property1 == rhs.property1) && (lhs.allData == rhs.allData)
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So I would need to create a logical check to compare each member variable?

Comment: Yes. Depending on your class definition, this may need to compare contents of members as well as the value of members (look-up deep compare, or deep equality). E.g. if allData in my example is another class, you may need to implement further Equatable implementations.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the topics you mentioned.

Comment: In the case of UNIT TESTING the mapping between 2 objects: I believe Equatable is not a good way of comparing 2 objects.

The reason I say this is you are testing your code to compare the objects and someone can easily add a new property and not add mapping or include the comparison of the new property in the func ==(lhs function.

So Equatable is likely not to compare all the properties and that defeats the purpose of comparing the 2 objects.

Having said that I still can't provide a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Did you just wanted to check for class kind, like below? similar to `[custom isKindOfClass: MyClass]`

```
guard customClass is MyClass else {
        XCTFail("FAILURE ")
        return 
    }
```

Edit:

Compare contents of two custom objects, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50645846/406627). After implementing the custom equatable method, use the below statement to check the unit test.

```
XCTAssert(object1 == object2)
```

Comment: OP asked for `compare the contents of two objects of the same class`.

Comment: `===` operator checks for reference of the object instead of the contents.

Comment: i mean, you need to compare the contents using the link provided(`static func ==(lhs:rhs)-> Bool`) and then compare using the `==` in your unit tests.