# Comparing two variables JavaScript

Tags: javascript, let

I am new to programming and JavaScript so please bear with me if its a stupid question.

I initialised two variables

```
let firstName = "blah";
let FirstName = "bleh";
```

When i write a below if statement i expected the output to be "right on" since the variable names are different (case-sensitive), but i get "boink". Could anyone kindly explain whats happening here?

```
if (firstName = FirstName) {
    console.log('boink')
} else {
    console.log('right on')
}
```

Comment: as has been written, just to elaborate a bit more on why it is as written below. `=` means now `firstName` will take on the value of `FirstName` whereas `===` is an exact comparison (of type and location in memory), meaning it is asking the question "is firstName the same as FirstName or not?" and `==` is an approximate comparison, this would not matter in your case.

Comment: @Michael you slightly misunderstand `===` - see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for more details. It does not have anything to do with location in memory.

Comment: sure does, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002819/difference-between-and

Comment: @Michael: that’s for Swift? this question is about JavaScript.

Comment: @Erik Allik it't the same in JS

Comment: @Michael yeah but isn’t it confusing to answer a JS question with a Swift answer...

Comment: It had a more clear explanation then the other ones I saw...it's a fact take it or leave it that's how JS works.

Comment: @Michael, but you're wrong. `const a = 5, b = 5; a === b // true` even though `a` and `b` do not share the same space in memory. `===` compares type and _value_, not memory location explicitly. In the case of objects, their "value" is a reference and objects with the same reference are considered equal by `===`.

Answer (score 2):

> Could anyone kindly explain whats happening here

Actually `firstName = FirstName` is an [Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2) expression and it will return the value on the right handside which is `"bleh"` which is truthy value. So the first block is executed

You are using assignment operator you need to use comparison operator(`==` or `===`)

```js
let firstName = "blah";
let FirstName = "bleh";

if (firstName === FirstName) {
    console.log('boink')
}
else {
    console.log('right on')
}
```

Comment: Why does it return *the value on the right handside*? Shouldn't it return like an empty string or undefined? +1

Comment: @k3lly.dev Try using `console.log(firstName = FirstName)` in the above snippet

Comment: I know it does, but since variable definitions in console return `undefined`, I was just curious about this behavior. Going to do a bit of research.

Comment: @k3lly.dev See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2 and read the first line **The assignment operation evaluates to the assigned value**

Comment: Thank you for the answer @MaheerAli

Comment: @Prashanth You are welcome. Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied witht it