# What is the difference between `!myValue.isEmpty` and `myValue.isEmpty == false` in Swift?

Tags: swift

Is there any difference between these statements, or can they be used as per developer preference?

```
!myValue.isEmpty
```

vs.

```
myValue.isEmpty == false
```

Curious to understand how they differ from a compiler point of view.

Comment: While using "== false" may be more obvious, I'd say using "!" is more common, as it's more compact, and it's consistent with the opposite "value.isEmpty".  "value.isEmpty == true" is a bit redundant/unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` is a logical NOT operator.

This reverses the Boolean value:

```
!value.isEmpty
```

`==` is a comparison operator.

This compares the bool value against another:

```
value.isEmpty == false
```

For Boolean variables both produce the same result.

---

Assuming `value.isEmpty` is `false`:

`!value.isEmpty` translates to `!false` which translates to `true`

`value.isEmpty == false` translates to `false == false` which translates to `true`

Comment: To add onto this, `==` checks if the two values/objects are the same, while `===` checks if the two objects share the same reference. More info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002819/difference-between-and)

Comment: so yes these are logically equivalent

Comment: @pawello2222 performance wise, does it make any difference ?

Comment: @Chaya No, it doesn't. It's just a matter of preference. You can take a look at [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136908/why-use-boolean-variable-over-boolean-variable-false)

Comment: @pawello2222 Great! this is what i was looking for.

Comment: @Chaya you might need to use `== false` and `== true` if you have an optional `Bool` because in this situation you would have a third possibility `== nil`